# How to initialize a 2D integer array using raw_input() in PYTHON

Tags: python, arrays, input, initialization, raw-input

I need to initialize a 2D integer array[10*10] taking input from user in PYTHON.
What is the code for this? I have tried doing this but it shows error as list index out of range

```
board = [[]]
for i in range(0,10):
    for j in range(0,10):
        board[i].append(raw_input())
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "solution.py", line 162, in 
    board[i].append(raw_input())
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: can you edit your code so that the indentation is correct?  Also, copy and paste the full traceback into your question

Comment: I have edited and the code and traceback is as follows.PLZ help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
board = []
for i in range(10):
    row = []
    for j in range(10):
        row.append(j)
        # row.append(raw_input())
    board.append(row)

>>> board
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]
>>>
```

For test purposes I inserted the counter instead of the raw_input value